# Loop through Leaflet Map layers

Tags: javascript, object, maps, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet JS to build my maps, but I'm having a few issues selecting layers.

I'm aiming to fit my map to a polygon. Leaflet generates a Leaflet ID for each element on the map, but these IDs are random. So I want to create an array which links each Leaflet ID with a known polygon ID.

The concept comes from here [How to interact with leaflet marker layer from outside the map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004226/how-to-interact-with-leaflet-marker-layer-from-outside-the-map) but I'm unsure how to implement it.

The object 'map._layers' stores all the elements including the ID of each polygon. So I'm looping through it as follows:

```
var idstore = [];   
for (var x in map._layers) {
  // here idstore[x['polyid']] = x;
}
```

Now I can use that array to associate my polygon IDs to Leaflet IDs. The resulting array should be as follows:

```
array('polygonid'=>'leafletid','155447'=>'478','748745' => 479);
```

My problem is the loop isn't working correctly. I can only see the first 2 records coming up which are actually overlays (map tiles). The elements are definitely in that object though.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13):

A good first step would be looking through the [Leaflet reference documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) and using the documented `.eachLayer` function instead of a for loop on a private variable.

```
var idstore = [];
map.eachLayer(function(layer){
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I've been using `eachLayer`. How do you break out of this loop?

Comment: You don't: eachLayer is not a traditional loop.

Comment: That's what I figured. I extended my own `eachLayer` and made it break on `return false` just like jQuery's `.each`. Thanks.

Comment: What was your code for that @Jeff?