# Leaflet markercluster: How can I create a markercluster with numbered markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to create a markercluster that has markers with IDs, because I would later like to remove a single marker from the map.  However, I'm having trouble even getting these labeled markers to appear on the map.  I'm loading them from a geoJSON formatted variable `individualPoints`.  I can add these markers to the map directly with the following code snippet:

```
// create object to save markers
var markersID = {};

// exchanges latitude & longitude
function switchLatLong(oldLocation) {
  return new L.LatLng(oldLocation[1], oldLocation[0]);
}

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    /* can add directly to the map--this works */
    markersID[feature.properties.id] = 
        L.marker(switchLatLong(feature.geometry.coordinates))
            .addTo(map);
  }
});
```

But I want them to be in a cluster, so I think I need to tag each marker with an ID (as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683871/assign-id-to-marker-in-leaflet)), then add this group to the cluster as follows:

```
var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    /* tag the marker with the id */
    markersID[feature.properties.id] = 
        L.marker(switchLatLong(feature.geometry.coordinates));
  }
});

// create a marker cluster group, and add the markers to this.
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({});
/* here's where I'm trying to toggle to use the markers with ID numbers */
//markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer); // this works
markers.addLayers(markersID);   // this doesn't
```

Adding `geoJsonLayer` works just fine, but adding `markersID` doesn't.  So I must be adding `markersID` incorrectly.
Here's a jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/anfw0n6w/

**Questions:**  Is there some better way to create markers that have an ID that I can refer to later?  How else can I add `markersID` to the markerClusterGroup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some better way to create markers that have an ID that I can refer to later?

There are ways that work :-)

> How else can I add `markersID` to the markerClusterGroup?

Since your `markersID` is a plain object, you cannot. `addLayer` accepts a Marker or a Layer Group (like your `L.geoJson`), and `addLayers` accepts an *array* of Markers.

Do not mix your need to refer to your markers later on, with the need to add them to your Marker Cluster Group.

What happens is that within your `onEachFeature`, you *duplicate* your Markers (create new ones) in `markersID`, instead of keeping a reference to the same `layer` that is built by `L.geoJson`. If you just keep a reference to `layer`, then you can refer directly to those markers, and you can directly add your `L.geoJson` layer group to your Marker Cluster Group:

```js
var markersID = {};

var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(individualPoints, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    // make a marker with that number
    // actually no need to duplicate the marker.
    //markersID[feature.properties.id] = L.marker(switchLatLong(feature.geometry.coordinates));
    markersID[feature.properties.id] = layer;
  }
});

markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer); // this works
map.addLayer(markers);

// This will work, you just need to get the appropriate `id`.
markers.removeLayer(markersID[id]);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/anfw0n6w/1/

Comment: Wow---thank you so much!  That's exactly what I needed.  I really appreciate that you clarified the difference between the markers group and the layers. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I appreciate that as well! :-)

Comment: In Leaflet vocabulary, everything you can add to the map (except for controls) is a _layer_ : a marker, a layer group, a tile layer, etc. As for your `markersID`, in JavaScript, `{}` makes it an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), aka associative array, or dictionary. `[]` would have made it an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), which is actually a specific type of object.

Comment: Mmmm, okay, that makes sense.  Thank you.  As a note to myself and others, I was able to get my original solution to work by defining `markersID` as an array (albeit still duplicating the markers, and needing to update the id value of `individualPoints` to yield a 0th entry). Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anfw0n6w/3/.  Your solution is definitely cleaner. :-)