# Extending $scope in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sometimes, i see people using this pattern:

`angular.extend($scope, {somekey, someval})`.

What is the benefit in using this style of scope extension, when i can set the scope directly like so:

`$scope.somekey = someval`?

Comment: No benefit, unless there are dozen of new properties. Then extend is a little cleaner.

Comment: Good question. In my opinion the first pattern is uglier and less readable somehow...but yeah whatever floats your boat

Comment: less code to write when you have bigger objects and extend once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the benefit in using this style of scope extension ?

If I read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7757f0a9e3dff7b1feb9994d750b5251230936c8/src/Angular.js#L326) correctly, absolutely none, despite syntactic pseudo-sugar that I personely don't agreee with.

Though, reading some [angular-leaflet](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) issues, one day, I remember I read someone stating that something worked with `angular.extend` and didn't with a simple assignment.

Comment: thank you. yes, angular-leaflet is where i saw this a lot, too.